# "ouvrier emboîteur" translation

Tags: traduction

What kind of work is "ouvrier emboîteur" per [Le Maitron](http://maitron-en-ligne.univ-paris1.fr/spip.php?article154428)? I can't find enough context for a translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans l'industrie horlogère suisse, l'emboiteur est un ouvrier qui a pour occupation de placer les mécanismes de montre dans leurs boitiers ([réf.](https://www.travailler-en-suisse.ch/metiers-touches-chomage.html)).

Le recueil de nomenclature suivant montre que ce métier est aussi ouvert aux femmes puisque le terme « emboiteuse » est utilisé ([réf.](https://www.mlrse.org/2/outils/rome.php?aff=a)). On vérifie de même que ce métier fait partie d'une catégorie qui dans l'horlogerie est appelée « montage en systèmes horlogers ».  Dans ce recueil on voit qu'il est catégorisé de la façon suivante.

B - ART ET FAÇONNAGE D'OUVRAGES D'ART
        B16 - Métal, verre, bijouterie et horlogerie
        B1604 - Réparation - montage en systèmes horlogers

Comme on trouve ce métier dans la nomenclature de Pôle emploi ([réf.](https://www.pole-emploi.fr/candidat/les-fiches-metiers-@/index.jspz?id=681)) son nom est aussi le nom français.

Le terme « ouvrier emboiteur » n'est plus utilisé dans la nomenclature officielle ([Pôle emploi](https://www.pole-emploi.fr/candidat/les-fiches-metiers-@/index.jspz?id=681) )  et on peut donc supposer qu'il s'agit de l'ancienne terminologie correspondant au terme moderne « emboiteur ».

Voici une description plus explicite de ce métier ([réf.](http://www.editions-chatiere.ch/SMD.C_/C.Editions/Les%20m%C3%A9tiers%20de%20l%27horlogerie/Muller%20Bernard.html)).

- Emboîteur      Un emboîteur expérimenté s’occupe de poser le mouvement dans la boîte en l’ajustant et en le fixant proprement. Le résultat de cet assemblage se nomme -« tête de montre ».

Il s'agit donc d'un métier ayant trait à ce que l'on pourrait appeler  en anglais « clock work encasing ». Je ne peux pas trouver s'il s'agit d'une spécialité dans le monde anglo-saxon.

Comment: Would "clockmaker" be an accurate synonym?

Comment: I'd say no; the clockmaker from what I gather is the person that puts together the clockwork. The "emboiteur" is to clock manufacturing what is to car manufacturing  the assembly worker that fasten the engine to the car. But as in this domain, there are various specialities; one man or woman by him/herself is rarely able to handle all the stages of clockmaking. I'd say "a special trade in the assembly of  clocks".